# how to ensure that random does not repeat value before all specified possible values have been exhausted in android-JAVA

Tags: android

how do i ensure that Random exhausts all possible values before calling a value the second time to make sure a song isn't repeated again before all have been played.

```
 MediaPlayer mp;
 Random rand= new Random();
 int iterator;
 int songs[][]={{R.raw.twenty,R.raw.forty,R.raw.twentyfive},{20,40,25}};
 play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 iterator=rand.nextInt(3);
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, songs[0][iterator]);
      mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {       
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          mp.release();
                                                 }
                }); 
    mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Shuffle the song list first and then play them in the order they were shuffled.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I would put the songs on a Arraylist, then call 
    
    `Collections.Shuffle(songlist);
    Random r = new Random();
    positionrandomsong = (r.nextInt(songslist.size())); 
    songtoplay = songlist.get(positionrandom);
    // then playsong :
    songtoplay songlist.remove(positionrandom);`

songlist should be a copy of all the songs on the list originalsongslist, surround that code with `if songlist.isempty` -- copy songs from originalsongslist to songlist.

hope gives you an idea..

Answer (score 0):

```
//Store paths of all the songs in a arrayList MusicFiles then initializeRandomArr 
    ArrayList<String > MusicFiles = null;
    ArrayList<Integer > arrIndicies;
    void initializeRandomArr()
    {
        int totalSize=MusicFiles.size();
        arrIndicies = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        for(int i=0; i<totalSize;i++)
        arrIndicies.add(i);
    }
    int RandomAccess()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomOutput = r.nextInt(arrIndicies.size());
        arrIndicies.remove(randomOutput);
        return randomOutput;
    }
    void playRandomSong()
    {
        if(arrIndicies.size()!=0)
        {
            playSong(MusicFiles.get(RandomAccess()));
        }
        else
        {
            initializeRandomArr();
            playSong(MusicFiles.get(RandomAccess()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll just provide an algorithm.

```
int array[] = new int[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    array[i] = i;

int rdmCode = getRandomCode(0, array.size);  
array.remove(rdmCode);
// use the rdmCode;
```

getRandomCode() should pick a random number from 0 to array.size. Then remove this number from array. Next time you pick a random number from the array, you won't get a repeated number.